# Name of a Mecha (horror?) anime movie. I know it is older and my parents had gotten it for me on dvd from best buy maybe 10-14 years ago

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, mecha

I have been recently trying to remember the name of an anime movie that I have hazy memories about. I think I remember it being mecha where humans in what I think is a military unit are fighting these monsters or creatures. I included horror in the title because I can sort of remember parts that were pretty graphic with deaths.

I remember 2 certain parts about the movie, the first is there was a scene where some person maybe a general or some higher up is having a conversation through a screen or monitor with what seems to be something that has a bunch of (human?) faces and I think I remember one of the faces having a deep voice.

The second scene I remember is for some reason some girl I think gets not eaten but gets beamed up into the middle of one of the creatures which I think was rather large compared to the others and some guy comes to save her. When he is saving her she is naked and they are floating around I believe. At the end of the movie it shows a trailer or something for the next one and I remember that it was snowy and I think there were wolves in it.

Sorry for most of it being unclear I had remembered it a while back and have searched for it for a bit but I could not find anything so I thought I would give this a shot.

Comment: Sounds like Evangelion to me; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13nSISwxrY4

Comment: It *could* be [Wolf's Rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf's_Rain) (wolves, snow...) but it's been 10+ years since I saw it.

Comment: maybe you check  Blue Gender? that was creatures attacks people, space station ,main characters girl and boy, but I don't remember or that was exactly scene like you write, and that was early 2000 show

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the second [Rebuild of Evangelion](https://evangelion.fandom.com/wiki/Rebuild_of_Evangelion) movie [Evangelion: 2.0
You Can (Not) Advance](https://evangelion.fandom.com/wiki/Evangelion:_2.0_You_Can_(Not)_Advance). It's a 2009 movie, so it's close to the time frame you mention

> I think I remember it being mecha where humans in what I think is a military unit are fighting these monsters or creatures.

That's Evangelion to a T.

> there was a scene where some person maybe a general or some higher up is having a conversation through a screen or monitor with what seems to be something that has a bunch of (human?) faces and I think I remember one of the faces having a deep voice

There's a scene where Gendo is reporting to [SEELE](https://evangelion.fandom.com/wiki/SEELE_(Rebuild)). While there are never any faces seen, the voices are mostly male and some are deep

[image: SEELE]

> The second scene I remember is for some reason some girl I think gets not eaten but gets beamed up into the middle of one of the creatures which I think was rather large compared to the others and some guy comes to save her. When he is saving her she is naked and they are floating around I believe.

Rei, piloting EVA Unit-00, attacks the 10th angel with what is basically a nuclear missile, but fails to destroy the angel. The angel then proceeds to eat Unit-00, with Rei still inside. This sends Shinji into a rage. He proceeds to return to Unit-01 and defeats the angel by merging with Unit-01. Unit-01 attains "godhood" and the fallen angel proceeds to turn into a giant naked Rei. Inside some internal scene with the interaction of Shinji and Rei, they are both floating.

While the giant naked Rei was part of End of Evangelion, the eating of Unit-00 was unique to this movie series and was not in the TV series, or End of Evangelion.